Linear loss value plot in stacked denoising autoencoder
I want to train a stacked denoising autoencoder to decode the feature matrix from 18930 dimentions to 60 dimentions. The initial feature matrix is sparse. My problem is why the train loss and validation loss curves are linear and if my implementation is truely a stacked denoising autoencoder?
Here is the code:
def min_max_normalization(feature_matrix_18930_random):
  scaler = MinMaxScaler()
  scaler.fit(feature_matrix_18930_random)
  feature_matrix_min_max=(scaler.transform(feature_matrix_18930_random))*1000
  return feature_matrix_min_max

def adding_noise(feature_matrix_min_max):
  feature_matrix_noised = np.zeros_like(feature_matrix_min_max)
  threshold=0.1
  a=int(18930*threshold)
  for i in range(feature_matrix_min_max.shape[0]):
    K = np.zeros(feature_matrix_min_max.shape[1])
    K[a:] = 1
    np.random.shuffle(K)
    feature_matrix_noised[i,:] = np.multiply(feature_matrix_min_max[i,:],K)
  return feature_matrix_noised

import random
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

feature_matrix=np.load('feature_matrix.npy')
feature_matrix_min_max=min_max_normalization(feature_matrix)
feature_matrix_noised=adding_noise(feature_matrix_min_max)

train=feature_matrix_min_max[:1050]
test=feature_matrix_min_max[1050:]

train_noised=feature_matrix_noised[:1050]
test_noised=feature_matrix_noised[1050:]

def stacked_denoising_autoencoder(train_noised,train,test_noised,test,feature_matrix_min_max):

  input_matrix = keras.Input(shape=(18930,))
  encoded = layers.Dense(2700, activation='relu')(input_matrix)
  encoded = layers.Dense(400, activation='relu')(encoded)
  encoded = layers.Dense(60, activation='relu')(encoded)

  decoded = layers.Dense(400, activation='relu')(encoded)
  decoded = layers.Dense(2700, activation='relu')(decoded)
  decoded = layers.Dense(18930, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

  adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=9.000000e-09)
  autoencoder = keras.Model(input_matrix, decoded)
  autoencoder.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy')
  history = autoencoder.fit(train_noised, train,
                    epochs=120,
                    batch_size=20,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(test_noised, test))
  encoder = keras.Model(input_matrix, encoded)
  encoded_matrix = encoder.predict(feature_matrix_min_max)
  return encoded_matrix,history

import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import Model

encoded_matrix_60,history=stacked_denoising_autoencoder(train_noised,train,test_noised,test,feature_matrix_min_max)

I tried different learning rates and eliminated the outliers but the plot is still linearenter image description here.
